# Error in Azure Function App VS 2019 .NET 3.0 - Method not found: 'IFunctionsHostBuilder.get_Services()'

Tags: azure, .net-core-3.0, azure-functions-runtime, entity-framework-core-3.0

Issue with Azure Functions/EFSQLSERVER .NET CORE 3.0:

To reproduce:

- Use Visual Studio 2019 16.2.1
- Use Azure Function template to create a project.
- Changed Target Framework to .NET Core 3.0
- Add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"    Version="3.0.0"
  reference via Nuget Package Manager.
- Excecut Function App using F5

Results in an error as showing in the following snippets.  Anyone came across this issue?

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1633 Commit hash: 45c7d86a3bbc9ed0a80a8f4199aa7ea80ccfb24e)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12673.0
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] Loading startup extension 'Startup'
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] Loaded extension 'Startup' (1.0.0.0)
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] Loading startup extension 'DurableTask'
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] Loaded extension 'DurableTask' (1.0.0.0)
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] A host error has occurred
[10/4/2019 6:13:14 PM] FunctionApp5: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder.get_Services()'.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider
```

My nuget packages from csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp5.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            **var x = builder.Services;**

        }
    }
}
```

[image: .NET Core 3.0]

[image]

Comment: This must be package issues as I have a similar problem.
Just by adding the http extensions package (Microsoft.Http.Extensions) I get this error (without using any code from that package).  By removing it, the error goes away.
I am on 16.3.2 with the same webjobs version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now,ASP.NET Core 3.0 not currently available for Azure App Service, check this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#aspnet-core-30-not-currently-available-for-azure-app-service).

Azure Functions 3.0, which will be fully compatible with Core 3.0, will be available in October, check [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/200). However it's not released now.

From this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/29), you could find Azure Function 2.0 right now does not work with any Microsoft.Extensions.* 3.* packages and cannot share code with .Net Core 3.0 services.

Further more information about Azure Fuction 3.0 check this [discussion](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/115).

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.

Comment: Rumor has it that the publish preview will be available by Oct. 25th

Answer (score 3):

You can now use .net core 3.0 to create azure functions. Update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.30-beta2` and set `AzureFunctionsVersion` to `v3-preview`.

Read more about Develop Azure Functions using .NET Core 3.0 [here](https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm)

[image]

You can now use DI using `IFunctionsHostBuilder`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(BI_Geo.AzureFunctions.Startup))]
namespace BI_Geo.AzureFunctions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IProcess, Process>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - in case the above fix is not working and the function project uses nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0, downgrade to 3.0.1 otherwise there will be the same error

Answer (score 1):

This saved my day

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add something else to look out for, the following was our issue:

- Our functions app referenced a Domain project
- Our Domain project referenced `"Microsoft.Extensions.Localization` version `5.0.1`, which in turn referenced a `5.x` version of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, which was incompatible with our 3.x runtime. Once we downgraded to reference `Microsoft.Extensions.Localization` version `3.1.10`, the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` reference downgraded with it and everything worked.

Comment: Took me an age to unravel this, but essentially no `v5.x` dependancies are compatible with .Net Core 3. These are .Net 5 runtimes. Annoyingly Nuget doesn't seem to care what version your targeting and offers to upgrade assemblies to v5 even if they'll break your build

Comment: I'm attempting to get [Nuget to address this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10455)

Answer (score -1):

Until Azure Functions 3.0 is available as a stable release, the easiest seems to be to downgrade the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package to 2.2.0:

It helped me with the same problem as there seems to be no other workaround in place for now. Even the available beta packages aren't working on a build server.

[image]

More details here: [Azure functions dependency injection - error when referencing class library](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1718) (Github).