# Problems with Azure Functions v3 app importing a .NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1

I building an .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions application on my local and am trying to import a .NET Core 3.1 class library into the Functions project, but when I do, I get the following error when I run the app:

`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder.get_ConfigurationBuilder()'. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`

I am using the ConfigurationBuilder in my Functions project:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Then I also use the configuration in a service in my library:

```
public MyService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

In my Functions project I added a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` as the error indicated that it couldn't find the ConfigurationBuilder definition.

I can import a .NET Standard 2.0 project without any errors. I read that Azure Funciton V3 is compatible with .NET Core 3.1 class libraries. I have tried downgrading `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` and played around with package versions, but nothing works.

Is what I am doing in my Functions project with Configuration incompatible with the .NET Core library? Why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no special needs, it is not recommended that you use a customized file to store the settings. In azure function v2&v3, settings in Values section of `local.settings.json` will be read as Environment variable(so I think there is no need to use customized file to store settings). Just use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` will be able to get the value. Generally, we only use `local.settings.json` for local development, and on azure portal we use configuration settings:

[image]

You can quickly add during deployment by Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: So I completely removed the retreival of the environement variables and use of the ConfigurationBuilder and I still get the error. I also tried removing the offending library, creating a blank .NET Core 3.1 class library, and importing as a dependency and the error shows up. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65427140/6569899) and tried changing versions but no luck.

Comment: I found part of the problem. I was extending FunctionsStartup for my startup class instead of WebJobStartup. When I switched to WebStartup my projects imported. However another problem popped up. I am not able to read my request headers for my http trigger. I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790036/functionsstartup-vs-iwebjobsstartup-problems-reading-httpheaders-on-the-request). If you have any recommendations, please let me know.