# .Net Core 3 Azure Function, Method not found: IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder.get_ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

The issue begun after I did a code cleanup, and updated some Nugets.

I tried to remove and reinstall all the Nugets, remove a project dependency that I added, searched for Nugets with .Net 5 dependency to downgrade, and still with the same problem.

The full massage is:

> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder.get_ConfigurationBuilder()'.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

The problem occurs **before the Startup**, in the Nuget **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs** version **3.0.25** in the class **WebJobsBuilderExtensions**, at the **startup.Configure(context, builder);** line.

```
private static void ConfigureAndLogUserConfigurationProviders(IWebJobsConfigurationStartup startup, WebJobsBuilderContext context, IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder builder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TrackedConfigurationBuilder>();

    if (builder.ConfigurationBuilder is ITrackedConfigurationBuilder tracker)
    {
        if (tracker != null)
        {
            tracker.ResetTracking();
            startup.Configure(context, builder);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{nameof(IConfigurationSource)}s registered by external startup type " + startup.GetType().ToString() + ":");

            foreach (IConfigurationSource source in tracker.TrackedConfigurationSources)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.Append($" {source.GetType().FullName}");
            }
            logger.LogDebug(new EventId(600, "ExternalConfigurationProviders"), sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue now, so thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you come across this link in your research? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790036/functionsstartup-vs-iwebjobsstartup-problems-reading-httpheaders-on-the-request

Comment: Ow….. Thank you, I did not find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a lot of tries, I found the culprid.

Like **Byron Jones** said, Nuget points to a newer version of some packeges that are not compatible with Core v3 Functions.

In my case was this 2, that were updated to 5.0, but the proper version would be 3.16

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this question a long after it was posted, but worth mentioning that to me it was a misconfiguration of `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` as `~3` after having the code updated that threw `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder.get_ConfigurationBuilder()'.`

After changing `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` and **saving** the value as `~4` matching the version of the code, it's not throwing the error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was still getting this error even after upgrading the FUNCTION_EXTENSION_VERSION, the .NET version, and the NuGet packages on the function app. However, I had referenced a number of Microsoft.X packages that were labeled 7.0. I had to revert all of the references to 6.0 for both my function app, AS WELL AS the chain of projects that were referenced in my code for the function app (it ran about 4 deep). I believe the 7.0 libraries only are compatible with Function Apps that run in Isolation Mode, which we are not using yet. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8984.