# Azure Function: Difference between IWebJobsStartup and FunctionsStartup

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using Azure Function(v3), I can register dependencies in startup.cs with both IWebJobsStartup and FunctionsStartup.

But which one we should use?

Registerd dependencies with IWebJobsStartup

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Notifications.Receiver
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventValidator, EventValidator>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventReceiverHandler, EventReceiverHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<InvoiceResultDto,InvoiceMessageEvent>, InvoiceMessageEventHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<InvoiceResultDto, InvoiceFileEvent>, InvoiceFileEventHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBusFactory, AzureServiceBusFactory>();

            builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Same dependencies I can also register with FunctionsStartup

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Notifications.Receiver
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventValidator, EventValidator>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventReceiverHandler, EventReceiverHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<InvoiceResultDto,InvoiceMessageEvent>, InvoiceMessageEventHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<InvoiceResultDto, InvoiceFileEvent>, InvoiceFileEventHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBusFactory, AzureServiceBusFactory>();

            builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FunctionsStartup` is derived from `IWebJobsStartup` so both will work as you have already experienced. Documentation will usually recommend using `FunctionsStartup` as it helps with some of the boilerplate code.

Comment: Hi, is there any documentation available for migrating from IWebJobsStartup to FunctionsStartup in Azure Function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, in Azure Functions the preferred way now to do dependency injection is by using the `FunctionsStartup`.

Yes, we have to implement the `Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)` method if we implement the **`IWebJobsStartup`** interface in **Startup.cs** class.

Whereas the [current MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services) says that the Startup class to inherit from **FunctionsStartup** class and also the **`Configure`** Method takes in an **`IFunctionsHostBuilder`**.

This similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66790036) explains the problems of reading HTTP Headers on the request in using **FunctionsStartup** vs **IWebJobsStartup** in **`Azure Functions .NET Applications`** and finally suggest the using **FunctionsStartup** is the ***better approach***.

Comment: Hi @anon, is there any documentation available for migrating from IWebJobsStartup to FunctionsStartup in Azure Function?